# Changing active menu item in response.menu

Tags: python, web2py

I can change the active menu item by redefining the complete menu structure 
in each function call, such as:

```
# default.py
def Item1():
    response.menu=[['Item1',True,URL('Item1')],
                  ['Item2',False,URL('Item2')]]
    ...
    return locals()

def Item2():
    response.menu=[['Item1',False,URL('Item1')],
                  ['Item2',True,URL('Item2')]]
    ...
    return locals()
```

Is there a more compact way such as 
`response.menu.activate(item1)` to do that?

I can find a remark on an argument `active_url`[here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#MENU), but I don't understand how to use this, can't find a syntax description.

**EDIT:**

I may not have fully understood Anthony's answer, since  I cannot get this running. Therefore I have now modified the code in a very brute force way to

```
# menu.py
response.menu=[['Item1',False,URL('Item1')],
               ['Item2',False,URL('Item2')]]


# default.py
def Item1():
    response.menu[0][1]=True
    ...
    return locals()

def Item2():
    response.menu[1][1]=True
    ...
    return locals()
```

I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant way to do this of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `MENU` helper, when you call it, you can specify the current URL as the active one:

```
MENU(response.menu, active_url=URL())
```

Note, `URL()` with no arguments returns the part of the URL containing the application, controller, and function for the current request. `URL(args=request.args)` also includes the current `request.args`, and finally, `URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars)` additionally includes the query string of the current request. If your menu item URLs include `args` or `vars`, then you will need to pass those as the `active_url` as well, or there will not be a match.

Alternatively, for each menu item, you can do something like:

```
current_url = URL(args=request.args, vars=request.vars)
response.menu = [
    ['Item1', URL('item1') == current_url, URL('item1')],
    ['Item2', URL('item2', args='arg1') == current_url, URL('item2', args1='arg1')],
    ...
]
```

To avoid the redundancy, you could try a helper like:

```
def menu_item(label, *args, **kwargs):
    url = URL(*args, **kwargs)
    return [label, url == URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars), url]

response.menu = [
    menu_item('Item1', 'item1'),
    menu_item('Item2', 'item2', args='args1'),
    menu_item('Item3', 'item3', args='args1', vars=dict(var1=1))
]
```

If you don't want to match the query string to determine the active URL, then exclude `vars=request.get_vars` from the call to `URL()` in `menu_item`.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is probably above my pay grade. maybe my brute fore workaround shown in the edit helps you better understand what I am aiming at.

Comment: Yes, the above addresses what you are aiming for, but it's difficult to know what else to say without knowing specifically what you tried from above and what results you got that were not expected.

Comment: I am looking for a preexisting command such as `response.menu.activate(item1)` which would allow me to activate an item by its name. I want to avoid using hard coded index numbers which I have to look up and which may change. Obviously, I could write my own function. Probably there is none.

Comment: No, what you are looking for does not exist, unless you are using the `MENU` helper, as noted in the first two lines of the above answer. I would recommend the approach shown above over your "brute force" approach, which will be highly error prone if you ever make changes to the menu.